# Remove last character from txt file

Tags: powershell

I need to remove last character in text file and set this content. First I have to find location the last character.

```
$dest= "K:\test.txt"

$count_characters= (Get-Content $dest | Measure-Object -Character).Characters
```

Now I know count of characters - the last one (`$count_characters`) I must remove and set content. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first access the last line using the array index `-1`. Then, You could use a simple regex which captures the whole line except the last chracter and replace it:

```
$dest= "K:\test.txt"
$replaceCharacter = 'A'

$content = Get-Content $dest
$content[-1] = $content[-1] -replace '^(.*).$', "`$1$replaceCharacter"
$content | Set-Content $dest
```

Comment: Yes - for this I can write -replace “.$” . But I need remove specific number of character  - for example character to position 250. Do you know? Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove them, you can use `.Split()` for example: `$content[-1] = $content[-1].Split(0,250)`